# JQM Message not showing up

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having a problem getting a simple header message to show up while using Jquery mobile 1.4.2. The message shows on page load then quickly disappears. I cannot figure out what is hiding the message from displaying. Weirdly enough, when I delete the 'panel' from the page the message shows, however I need the panel for the functionality of the page. Also, while messing around with the Jsfiddle I noticed that earlier versions of JQM displayed the message properly. Thanks

Jsfiddle is http://jsfiddle.net/sAKq5/

```
<div data-role="page" id="pager">
       <div data-role="panel" id="addpanel" data-position="right" data-animate="false">
        </div>


        <div class="header" data-role="header">
        </div>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
            <h3>Your Table </h3>
            <table id="xx">
            </table>
            <ul id="xxx">
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="actionMsg"> 
            <h5> Message holder at length </h5> 
        </div>

        <div class="footer" data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed" class="actionMsg">
            <h2>
                Powered by
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding in the line

```
 z-index: 1000;
```

into the css allows the message to be shown. If z-index is less than 1000, message still is not shown.